# How to read FileNames in a given Folder on MAC?

Tags: vba, macos, filenames

My goal is to read the FileNames of all png files in a given folder.

I've Windows VBA code which uses the ActiveX FileSystemObject.

On a MAC This code results in

> "runtime error 429 activex component can't create object"

```vb
Function ReadFileNames(ByVal sPath As String) As Integer
    
    Dim oFSO, oFolder, oFile As Object
    Dim sFileName As String
                        
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.getfolder(sPath)
            
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        
        If Not oFile Is Nothing And Right(LCase(oFile.Name), 4) = ".png" Then  ' read only PNG-Files
            sFileName = oFile.Name
            ' do something with the FileName ...
        End If
        
    Next oFile
        
End Function
```

Comment: You can use the native VBA command DIR to list files in drive mapped folder (not fileshares)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Could you share some code snippet? I have to admit, I have no idea what exactly you mean or how to translate that into code... to store the Filenames as Strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sub, using the native VBA DIR command, listing EXCEL workbooks in a folder by printing their names on the debug window:

```
Public Sub DirXlList()
    Const cstrPath As String = "c:\users\xxxx\misc\"
    Dim strDirItem As String
    strDirItem = Dir(cstrPath & "*.xlsx")
    While strDirItem <> ""
       Debug.Print "FileName: " & strDirItem, "FullPath: " & cstrPath & strDirItem
       strDirItem = Dir()
       DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Does this help? In

Update: doevents command allows Excel to process other pending user interface activities, such as window refreshes, mouse-clicks. If you have lots of files (thousands) in a folder, Excel may appear unresponsive/frozen in a loop like this. It is not necessary, as it will become responsive again, once it completes the loop. If you have only a few hundred files then it is an overkill. Remove and try.

Comment: Ok... I'll try to test that... at the moment I have no idea what "DoEvents" does. Is that line necessary? And the "strDirItem" Variable then holds one single filename at a time, I guess? Thanks for your kind help!!

Comment: I added an explanation of why I used doevents. In my test case I had over 10kfiles, and excel appeared unresponsive while processing the loop without it. Yes, you use strDirItem as the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

VBA for Mac can link to the entire c standard library, like this example:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory_byPtr Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (ByVal dest As LongPtr, ByVal src As LongPtr, ByVal size As Long) As LongPtr
```

I'm too lazy to write out relevant examples for you, but if, by chance, you are familiar with using the c standard library for file manipulation, you can just do it that way.

Comment: Oh, this looks interesting, too. If I find out this can work better for me, I'll stick to that. Thank you!! :-)